# How do I restrict users from setting focus to a specific cell? VB.NET

Tags: windows, vb.net, datagridview

I have a DGV with 5 Columns, i want to make selectable only (1 and 4)Columns.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/268708/Prevent-Focus-at-Particular-Cell-of-DataGridView

Comment: Hey many Thanks, please put it on a answer for +Rep :)